# Properly reading files with FileReader and BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am trying to learn how to use read files using FileReader in Java however I get persistent errors. I am using Eclipse and I get a red error indicating that The constructor FileReader(File) is 
undefined and The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined; however, I do not know where this error is originating from because I am using the right libraries and statements.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor FileReader(File) is undefined
    The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined
    at FileReader.main(FileReader.java:17)
```

My code is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("example.txt");

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line;

            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + file.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file.toString());
        }
        finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to close file: " + file.toString());
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            }
        }



    }

}
```

For extra context (Sorry about the size but I believe you can zoom in. You can see where to red errors are on the left of the line): 
[image]

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you named your own class `FileReader`, and it's conflicting with the `java.io.FileReader` you want to use. This is what the red line under the import is telling you: Importing won't work because you have a different class with the same name that's shadowing the import. Change the name of your class.

Comment: FileReader should not be the class name when we deal with file reading operation.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("example.txt");

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            java.io.FileReader fr = new java.io.FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line;

            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + file.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file.toString());
        }
        finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to close file: " + file.toString());
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Actually  your class `FileReader`  is hiding `java.io.FileReader`. Above should work now